# Issue in using modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to get value chosen in modal target div but i cant get it

```
<a href="#" id="invoker" data-target="#options" data-toggle="modal" data-bind="value:selectedValue"></a>
```

div contains id options.

```
<div class="modal hide" id="options" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="violation-modal" aria-hidden="true">
<select id="cars" name="cars" data-bind="options:cars,optionsValue : id,optionsText : name,value : carName"></select>
</div>
```

When i use the above select tag and its contents, i can get the selected values in viewmodel.But i tried to get the selected values in div(having id as options) from a(id="invoker") tag,i cant get it(i.e by using modals).

Someone please help me.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pravinkumart/Fp63v/)

Here is the outcome i need.
chosen value in select tag to be stored in selectedValue in 'a' tag from it is called

Comment: can you post the full page and the corresponding viewmodel?

Comment: i have added it in fiddle..please help

Comment: add in the bootstrap javascript or else the codes you are using wont work.

Comment: @Chanckjh i have added in fiddle

Comment: also you need to add in the knockout framework to your fiddle.

Comment: This is closer, but not fully functional, unfortunately I have to run...http://jsfiddle.net/pltaylor3/wK3ZK/

Comment: Thank you every one for responses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your select binding, you store the value in carName observable.

you can use it the way you want in your a tag binding.

Here's a simple example using your Fiddle :

```
<a href="#" data-target="#options" data-toggle="modal" data-bind="text:carName, attr: {selectedValue:carName}"></a>

<div class="modal hide" id="options" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="violation-modal" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<select id="cars" name="cars" data-bind="options:cars,optionsValue : 'id',optionsText : 'name',value : carName"></select>
```

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RapTorS/Fp63v/5/

Answer (score 0):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pltaylor3/wK3ZK/) should have what you need.  Documentation is [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) and [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

```
<select id="cars" name="cars" data-bind="options: cars, optionsText:'id', optionsvalue:'name', selectedOptions:carName"></select>
```